# Compare two numbers and return -1, 0 or 1

Tags: c#

Is there a simple math function available that compares numbers x and y and returns -1 when x is less than y, 1 when x is more than y and 0 when they're equal?

If not, would there be a elegant solution (without any `if`'s) to convert the output of `Math.Max(x, y)` to these returns? I was thinking of dividing the numbers by themselves, e.g. 123/123 = 1 but that will introduce the problem of dividing by 0.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For your strict -1, 0 or 1 requirement, there's no single method that is guaranteed to do this. However, you can use a combination of [`Int32.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2ky8xsk.aspx) and [`Math.Sign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd3y5wdf.aspx):

```
int value = Math.Sign(x.CompareTo(y));
```

Alternatively, if you're happy with the normal `CompareTo` contract which is just stated in terms of negative numbers, positive numbers and 0, you can use `CompareTo` on its own.

Comment: I'm actually starting to wonder whether the return value I need isn't the `Int32.CompareTo`. return after all. In each case, your answer provides the methods I need and is the best answer to my question.. so accepted :)

Comment: Can you give an example where `Int32.CompareTo()` returns something other than -1|0|1 ?

Comment: @ChrisGessler: Not offhand - but it would be entirely reasonable for it to do so (given the documentation), and I wouldn't want to *assume* that it never will.

Comment: I reflected out the code for Int32.CompareTo() and it doesn't return anything but -1|0|1, however, maybe some other number objects do like Double or Decimal.

Comment: Why do you also need Math.Sign ?

Comment: @nights: Because that's guaranteed to return -1, 0 or 1, whereas `CompareTo` isn't. I'm not quite sure what you're proposing instead.

Answer (score 15):

You can do it without using any .NET calls at all and on 1 line. **NOTE**: Math.Sign and type.CompareTo both use logical if statements and comparison operators which you said you wanted to avoid.

```
int result = (((x - y) >> 0x1F) | (int)((uint)(-(x - y)) >> 0x1F));
```

as a function

```
//returns 0 if equal
//returns 1 if x > y
//returns -1 if x < y
public int Compare(int x, int y)
{
    return (((x - y) >> 0x1F) | (int)((uint)(-(x - y)) >> 0x1F));
}
```

Basically, all this does is [SHIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) the sign bits all the way to the first position. If the result is unsigned then it will be 0; then it does the same operation and flips the sign bits then [OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)s them together and the result is wither 1, 0 or -1.

Case where result is -1

```
IS 12 > 15:

12 - 15 = -3            (11111111111111111111111111111101)
-3 >> 0x1F = -1         (11111111111111111111111111111111)

-(12 - 15) = 3          (00000000000000000000000000000011)
3 >> 0x1F = ((uint)0)=0 (00000000000000000000000000000000) cast to uint so 0

    11111111111111111111111111111111
OR
    00000000000000000000000000000000
=   11111111111111111111111111111111 (-1)
```

Case where result is 1

```
IS 15 > 12:

15 - 12 = 3               (00000000000000000000000000000011)
3 >> 0x1F = 0             (00000000000000000000000000000000)

-(15 - 12) = -3           (11111111111111111111111111111101)
-3 >> 0x1F = ((uint)-1)=1 (00000000000000000000000000000001) cast to uint so 1

    00000000000000000000000000000000
OR
    00000000000000000000000000000001
=   00000000000000000000000000000001 (1)
```

Case where result is 0

```
IS 15 == 15:

15 - 15 = 0               (00000000000000000000000000000000)
0 >> 0x1F = 0             (00000000000000000000000000000000)

-(15 - 15) = 0            (00000000000000000000000000000000)
0 >> 0x1F = ((uint)0)=0   (00000000000000000000000000000000) cast to uint so 1

    00000000000000000000000000000000
OR
    00000000000000000000000000000000
=   00000000000000000000000000000000 (0)
```

This should also be much faster than using any calls to Math or any other .NET methods.

Answer (score 6):

```
x.CompareTo(y)
```

Straight from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2ky8xsk.aspx).

Comment: Upvoting this one because the MSDN page shows how to coerce the value into -1/0/+1. Without that, `CompareTo()` doesn't actually do what the OP wants.

Comment: @egrunin - I don't see in the article where it shows how to coerce the value into -1/0/+1. If you're referring to the cast to the Comparison enum, `(Comparison)100` would still be 100, not 1.

Comment: I haven't run that code, but it *appears* to claim that `(Comparison)100` will return `Comparison.GreaterThan`, which (if then cast to `int`) would equal 1.

Comment: In my tests (C# + .NET 4.0) `CompareTo` does happen to return either -1, 0 or 1 so the example would work.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `CompareTo()` function

```
int i = 5;
int n = 6;

int c = i.CompareTo(n);
```

I generally use it in `if` statements:

```
int x = 34;
int y = 25;

if(x.CompareTo(y) == 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Yes, they are equal");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("No, they are not equal");
}
```

Edit:

After some people claimed that Int32.CompareTo() could return something other than -1|0|1, I decided to research the possibility myself.

Here's the reflected code for `Int32.CompareTo()`.  I fail to see how either one would ever return anything but -1|0|1.

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public int CompareTo(int value)
{
    if (this < value)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (this > value)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


public int CompareTo(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (!(value is int))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_MustBeInt32"));
    }
    int num = (int) value;
    if (this < num)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (this > num)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this isn't guaranteed to return -1 or 1.

Comment: Ahh, yes I almost forgot about that with ints.  I generally compare strings which does return -1 | 0 | 1.

Comment: ints typically do as well.  It's just that the contract for CompareTo only guarantees a positive, negative, or zero value and not {-1,0,1}.

Comment: @AustinSalonen - after some research, I have not found a single example where `Int32.CompareTo()` returned anything other than -1|0|1.

Comment: Indeed.  The key word there was "guarantees," which means MS or the Mono team doesn't have to provide that same functionality (or may not have in past releases).  Pairing it with Math.Sign does _guarantee_ -1|0|1.

Comment: @AustinSalonen - Gotcha.  Makes sense.  Thanks for taking the time to explain it further.

Answer (score 1):

It's the Math.Sign() function.

Like this:

```
return Math.Sign(x-y);
```

Comment: My downvote was for your `Math.Sign` without further explanation, now removed. But with the `x-y`, it misbehaves on overflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code

```
var result = a.CompareTo(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2ky8xsk.aspx) Method on an integer:

```
public int c(int x, int y)
{
  return x.CompareTo(y);
}

void Main()
{       
    Console.WriteLine(c(5,3));
    Console.WriteLine(c(3,3));
    Console.WriteLine(c(1,3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried use `compareTo()`? Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2ky8xsk.aspx